# Perturbation method to solve $\epsilon x^3=x+\epsilon$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I was given the following exercise:

> Find two-term approximation to the real roots of the equation
> $\epsilon x^3=x+\epsilon \tag*{}$

**My attempt:**

Since this is a singular equation, we introduce a change of variable $x=\delta y$ with $y\simeq 1$. Substitute this to the equation and we get

$\epsilon \delta^3 y^3 = \delta y +\epsilon \tag*{}$

To find the appropriate form of $\delta$, we use the method of dominant balance. We take the balance $\epsilon \delta^3 y^3\simeq \delta y$ and we have $\delta \simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Substitute back and we get

$\frac{y^3}{\sqrt{\epsilon} } = \frac{y}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} +\epsilon\tag*{}$

or

$y^3 =y +\epsilon^{3/2}\tag*{}$

Expand $y$ with $y=y_0 +y_1 \epsilon+\cdots $. Then we have

$y_0^3+3y_0^2y_1\epsilon +... = y_0+y_1\epsilon +\epsilon^{3/2}\tag*{}$

If we compare the coefficient of $\epsilon^{3/2}$ term, we have $0=1$.

(I am stuck here)

---

Since the expansion $y=y_0 +y_1 \epsilon+...$ gives contradiction, I think we need to use another expansion, but I am not sure which kind of expansion I should use.

Comment: Maybe $$x=\epsilon^{-1/2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}-\frac{3\epsilon^{5/2}}{8}+\dots$$

Comment: How about expanding $y$ in $\epsilon^{3/2}$ in place of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @SangchulLee It gave me $y_0^3+3y_0^2y_1\epsilon^{1/2}+3y_0y_1^2\epsilon +\epsilon^{3/2}y_1^2 = y_0+\epsilon^{1/2}y_1 +\epsilon^{3/2}$. Comparing the leading order gave me $y_0=0, \pm 1$, and comparing the coefficient of $\epsilon^{3/2}$ gave me $y_1 =\pm 1$, but comparing the coefficient of $\epsilon^{1/2}$ gave me $3y_0^2y_1=y_1$ which is not going to be true for any $y_0,y_1$.

Comment: Well, if you decided to use $y=\sum_i y_i\epsilon^{i/2}$, then $$ y^3 = y_0^3 + 3 y_0^2 y_1 \epsilon^{1/2} + (3 y_0^2 y_2+3 y_0 y_1^2) \epsilon + (3 y_0^2 y_3+6 y_0 y_1y_2+y_1^3) \epsilon^{3/2} + \cdots.$$ I think you forgot to include higher-order terms when cubing $y$. Anyway, considering that the leading error term in the right-hand side is $\epsilon^{3/2}$, I would expand $y$ in $\epsilon^{3/2}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Since the problem said two-term expansion I thought I should use $y=y_0+y_1 \epsilon^{1/2}$. Did I misunderstand the meaning of it? how should I interpret the word "two-term"?

Comment: If you are looking at the two-term expansion in $\epsilon^{1/2}$, then you are discarding all the higher-order terms, So, the two-term expansions of both sides in $\epsilon^{1/2}$ will be $$ y_0^3 + 3y_0^2 y_1 \epsilon^{1/2} + \text{[higher order terms]}= y_0 + \text{[higher order terms]}. $$ Comparing both sides gives $y_0 = 0, \pm 1$ and $y_1 = 0$, which simply tells that $\epsilon^{1/2}$ is not the correct scale for the leading error term. If you want to make use of higher-order terms, then you need to use more precise expansion.

Comment: @SangchulLee Why is it not the correct scale? Is it because since $y_1=0$ we only have one term and it is not "two-term"?

Comment: Yes. It tells that the actual error term is much smaller than $\epsilon^{1/2}$, thereby rendering the coefficient $y_1$ of $\epsilon^{1/2}$ zero. Even though this is not wrong, the resulting expansion is not conveying any useful information about asymptotic behavior of $y$. So, you would want to expand $y$ in a different variable if you wish to discover the second "non-trivial" term.

Comment: @SangchulLee Okay, thank you. So going back to the original question, how do we know that the leading error term should be $\epsilon^{3/2}$? Is it guess and check or is there a systematic way?

Comment: I am not sure about any systematic approach, but the general idea is like this: if the leading error terms of $y$ and $y^3$ are different, then $\epsilon^{3/2} = y^3 - y$ will capture the difference in leading terms. So it would be reasonable to expect that $\epsilon^{3/2}$ is the leading order. (Of course, this argument will break down if the leading error terms of both sides cancel out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from $y^3=y+\epsilon^{3/2}$ from the question.

Let $y = y_0 + y_1\epsilon^{\gamma}+\cdots$ where $\gamma$ is a constant.
$y_0$ is the solution to $y^3=y$. That is, $y_0=0,1,-1$

We use the method of dominant balance to find the appropriate $\gamma$. By substituting the expansion to the equation, we get the following equation.

$y_0^3 + 3y_0^2y_1\epsilon^{\gamma}+\cdots = y_0 + y_1 \epsilon^{\gamma}+\cdots + \epsilon^{3/2} \tag*{}$
Since $y_0^3=y_0$,

$3y_0^2y_1\epsilon^{\gamma}+\cdots =y_1 \epsilon^{\gamma}+\cdots + \epsilon^{3/2} \tag*{}$

We consider $\epsilon^{\gamma}\simeq \epsilon^{3/2}$ and every other term is negligible. Then we have $\gamma \simeq 3/2$. We can easily see that this value is consistent with the balance. Therefore set $\gamma = 3/2$.

Now consider $O(\epsilon^{3/2})$ terms. By comparing the coefficient, we have
$3y_0^2y_1=y_1+1\tag*{}$

By solving this, we have

$\displaystyle y_1 = \frac{1}{3y_0^2-1}\tag*{}$

For $y_0=0,1,-1$, the value is $y_1 =-1, 1/2, 1/2$, respectively. Therefore, we have three asymptotic solution for $y$:

$\begin{align} y &= -\epsilon^{3/2}+\cdots \\ y &= 1 +\frac{\epsilon^{3/2}}{2} +\cdots \\ y=&= -1 +\frac{\epsilon^{3/2}}{2} + \cdots \\ \end{align}\tag*{}$

By using $x=y/\sqrt{\epsilon}$, we have the following solutions:

$\begin{align} x &= 0-\epsilon +\cdots \\ x &= \epsilon^{-1/2} +\frac{\epsilon}{2} +\cdots \\ x &= -\epsilon^{-1/2} +\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \cdots \\ \end{align}\tag*{}$

Observe that one of the solutions matches the expansion mentioned in the comment.

Comment: $y_0 = 0$ gives $y_1 = -1$. Alternatively, take $x = A \epsilon^p$. Show that $3 p + 1 = 1$ doesn't work, because the remaining term isn't negligible. That leaves either $p = 1$ or $3 p + 1 = p$. If $p = 1$, then $-A - 1 = 0$. If $p = -1/2$, then $A^2 - 1 = 0$. Next, take $x = -\epsilon (1 + A \epsilon^p)$ and repeat the procedure (since $0 - \epsilon$ is not likely to count as a two-term expansion :)).